# MySQL SELECT rows between two values

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select data from a mysql database from the past 12 months based on the current date. I have the dates saved in the database as unix timestamps but my query does not seem to work.

```
$query="SELECT user_id, COUNT(first_name) AS member_count
FROM main_user
WHERE renew_date<'$time' AND renew_date>'$old_time' WHERE renew_date!=''";
```

Basically I need to count all instances of first_name where there is a renew_date timestamp.

Comment: even your variable names says us that DATE cant be compared with TIME.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an additional `WHERE` where you should use `AND`:

```
$query="SELECT user_id, COUNT(first_name) AS member_count
FROM main_user
WHERE renew_date<'$time' AND renew_date>'$old_time' AND renew_date!=''";
                                                    ^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your query, you have two WHERE clauses!

Answer (score 1):

You put **`WHERE` twice**. You can use [From_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function in mysql

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(renew_date)<NOW() 
    AND FROM_UNIXTIME(renew_date)> (NOW()-INTERVAL 1 year)
    AND renew_date !=''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find this and other errors, when you test the return value from your query

```
$query = 'select ...';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($result === false) {
    // error handling
    echo $mysqli->error;
} else {
    // query successful
    // process result set
}
```