# Split a fetch all array into separate arrays

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can i split a Dabble fetch all query into separate arrays?
I'd divide, for ex, 1 million records into 10 arrays and make the same operation for every array..
I've this problem because i've tofind a way to not overload php memory buffer..

Many thanks,
steve

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_chunk to do that.
Basically give the database fetch result to the function.

You can check this link:
http://php.net/manual/tr/function.array-chunk.php

**EDIT**

```
for($x=0; $x<30; $x++)
    $mainArray[]="Data X";

$split=array_chunk($mainArray,3);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($split);
echo "</pre>";
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Data X
        [1] => Data X
        [2] => Data X
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Data X
        [1] => Data X
        [2] => Data X
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Data X
        [1] => Data X
        [2] => Data X
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Data X
        [1] => Data X
        [2] => Data X
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Data X
        [1] => Data X
        [2] => Data X
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Data X
        [1] => Data X
        [2] => Data X
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Data X
        [1] => Data X
        [2] => Data X
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => Data X
        [1] => Data X
        [2] => Data X
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => Data X
        [1] => Data X
        [2] => Data X
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => Data X
        [1] => Data X
        [2] => Data X
    )

)
```

Comment: I know, but with chunk fn i'll split one array into N arrays. I need a fn that every X records (for ex. 100000) create a chunk...

Comment: You can split the main array into smaller arrays by every X recors, for example if the $mainArray has 20 rows, you can split it 5 by 5 with array_chunk($mainArray,5);

Comment: :@  And how can i obtain the numbers of generated arrays?

Comment: $newArrays=array_chunk($mainArray,5);  and  $numberOfNewArrays=count($newArrays);

Comment: p.s. array_chunk($mainArray,5); doesn't split every 5 records but split in 5 arrays....this isn't  what i'm searching...

Comment: It splits given array into given records. Has nothing to do with new array count. I've added an example code, test it yourself.

Comment: i tried to do that but (simulating memory buffer of my server that has 2 GB) splitting go in "Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1633681408) (tried to allocate 256 bytes)".
Another solution to manipulate 1 million records? i have to make some fn every 100k contacts..

Comment: You need to limit the results coming from database query. If you want to do an operation on 1m results, any PHP function would give this error if you don't have enough buffer. You should use SQL to limit fetched rows.

Comment: can you make me an example? if i use limit of X records i give X records in my array..How can i get from X to Y in the next query?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727076/mysql-select-rows-between-two-values) You will use something similar to this and you'll limit the results like 50k or 100k (depends to your buffer) and you'll work on that results. Otherwise since you're calling 1m results, buffers won't accept that - does not matter how many arrays you cut it, your memories are holding it all.